# Is the word in genesis 1water or waters?

Tags: symbolism

My question is about the use of the word water in Genesis 1. Is it

translated as Water or Waters? Where there many bodies of water in

creation or just one? Many pieces of land or just one?

Comment: Please quote the the specific verse you are asking about, and indicate which translation you are using. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"In Hebrew, the plural is not only used to indicate multiplicity, but also to express the idea of strength and intensity implied in life.  Thus words like 'heaven, water, face, blood' are always used in the plural in order to express the idea of fullness of life contained in these notions." - Doukan, Jacques B.  *Hebrew for Theologians: A Textbook for the Study of Biblical Hebrew in Relation to Hebrew Thinking*.  University Press of America: New York.  1993.  Page 77.

Answer (score -1):

"Water or waters ?"

I believe the answer is in the passage. "Waste" and "void" [AV] are *tohu* and *bohu* in Hebrew. "Inglorious" and "standing out, starkly" as I understand the words to mean.

Young's Literal, The AV, The Hebrew Interlinear and J N Darby all translate *mayim* as the plural, "waters".

The waste and void are described, abstractly. Then the same scenario is further described in terms of landscape. The Spirit of God "hovers" or "flutters" - *rachaph* - above this expanse, but does not descend upon it.They are not, yet, organised, but there shall in the future - there must in the future - be a time of separation of that which is within the obscurity.

It is inglorious - and markedly so. It is an expanse of volume that is dark upon its surface. Thus, its depths are obscured. There is no way of knowing what is within it. It is plural, but not definable into categories; all that can be discerned is a multiple and fluid *something.*

This is not a technical description of the mechanics of Creation, I believe. It is a very spiritual description of what was there, as such.

And soon, in Genesis, there appears something out of the darkness - one who behaves like a Serpent - who focuses his attention on those who are within the provision, and under the instruction, of Another Spirit.

Nigel